# Scaling a div tooltip in a d3 force diagram

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am new to d3 and javascript in general. I build this fiddle here, which is a basic d3 force diagram, with an .onmousover event which shows a div tooltip when the user hovers over a node

https://jsfiddle.net/1qe1gp06/20/

the content from the tooltip comes from the node data

```
   var nodes = [
    { x:   width/3, y: height/2, "content":"small" },
    { x: 2*width/3, y: height/2,   "content":"biggerbiggerbiggerbiggerbiggerbigger"}
   ];
```

d3 node javascript

```
var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);
        div.html(d.content + "<br/>" + d.content + "<br/>" + d.content + "<br/>" + d.content + "<br/>" )
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);
        })
                ;
```

append div tooltip

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);
```

css for the div tooltip

```
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 15px "Courier New";
  color: #F2F3F4;
  background: #5D6D7E;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #BDC3C7;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

However, I don't know how to scale the tooltip so that it expands or shrinks based upon the length of the text or number of line breaks in the content.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qybNM.png)

It is probably easiest seen in the fiddle

can anyone help please?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Your jsfiddle seems not to be working.  When I click run it doesn't do anything.  A few tips: 1 you have a     <script> at the end of your html  2) you'll want to put your css in the CSS box, not in the HTML box   3) likewise with javascript; jsfiddle doesn't work well with js  in the HTML box.  For adding js references (like to d3), you can add those in the "Resources" section on the left of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked and updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x98at09p/2/) I had to make a few corrections so it would run (probably just some typos and not relevant to the question). The thing that needed changing was:

```
div.tooltip {
  width: 200px;
}
```

to

```
div.tooltip {
  width: max-content;
}
```

Hard coding a width will enforce that width regardless of the elements contents. `max-content` will basically make the div as big as it needs to be to fit what is inside. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content)

Comment: perfect, that is exactly what I wanted. thanks so much. yes, there was a typo https://jsfiddle.net/1qe1gp06/36/

Comment: I have encountered the same issue many times so glad I could help!